# Nested ViewPager returns null after rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need a reference to `VerticalViewPager` in `PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens`.

I got two ViewPagers: one for horizontal swiping that goes on for ever, and one for vertical swiping that loads three fragments (mid, swipe up, swipe down) that loads content. The horizontal ViewPager loads a new instance of `VerticalViewPager` on every swipe. I need a reference in the actual fragment that is loaded by the `VerticalViewPager`, so that I can swipe vertically by tapping a button. I also need a reference to the horizontal `ViewPager` to allow the first page to have a button that triggers a horizontal swipe.

I've solved it by sending the reference as an argument like this:

`FragSanningEllerKonsekvens` - The class that initializes the `VerticalViewPager`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sanning_eller_konsekvens, container, false);
    initComponents();
    setComponents();
    return view;
}

private void initComponents() {
    verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.verticalviewpager);
    mStatementPagerAdapter = new TruthDarePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()).newInstance(getChildFragmentManager(),mViewPager, verticalViewPager);
}
```

Its transfers in `TruthOrDarePagerAdapter`:

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private VerticalViewPager mVerticalViewPager;
public static TruthDarePagerAdapter newInstance(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager mViewPager, VerticalViewPager mVerticalViewPager){
    TruthDarePagerAdapter horizontalPagerAdapter = new TruthDarePagerAdapter(fm);
    horizontalPagerAdapter.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    horizontalPagerAdapter.setVerticalViewPager(mVerticalViewPager);
    return horizontalPagerAdapter;
}


public VerticalViewPager getVerticalViewPager() {
    return mVerticalViewPager;
}

public void setVerticalViewPager(VerticalViewPager mVerticalViewPager) {
    this.mVerticalViewPager = mVerticalViewPager;
}

private void setViewPager(ViewPager mvViewPager){
    this.mViewPager = mvViewPager;
}

private ViewPager getViewPager(){
    return mViewPager;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens frag = new PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens().newInstance(getViewPager(), getVerticalViewPager());
.
.
.
    return frag;
}
```

`PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens` - The class that needs the reference.

```
public static PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens newInstance(ViewPager mViewPager, VerticalViewPager mVerticalViewPager){
    PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens frag = new PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens();
    frag.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    frag.setVerticalViewPager(mVerticalViewPager);
    return frag;
}


private void setupMenu() {


    viewTop = view.findViewById(R.id.sek_top);
    viewBottom = view.findViewById(R.id.sek_bottom);

    viewTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getVerticalViewPager().setCurrentItem(0, true);
        }
    });

    viewBottom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getVerticalViewPager().setCurrentItem(2, true);
        }
    });
}
```

**The code above works excellent until I rotate the device.** After rotation the `getVerticalViewPager()` returns `null`. **In other parts of the application I've used this pattern without any problems:** on rotation the ViewPager is sent as a parameter and the application reloads without dropping the reference.

So the conclusion I've drawn is that the `VerticalViewPager` doesn't get reinitialized on rotation, while `PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens` is.

My question is; how can I solve it? Can I force it to be reinitialized, or can I obtain a reference to it in some other way?

EDIT 1: I'll think its related to `getItem()` in the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. It will be called to allocate 3 fragments at every given time. I *think* this might nullify the `getVerticalViewPager()` method.

**EDIT 2: I moved some code to allow the  `ViewPager` and the button to be initialized in the same class, thus making it somewhat null-proof. Thanks for the help!**

Comment: Not having any knowledge of what goes on 'under the hood' of your app, I personally prefer to have either an Activity or Fragment as a parent that maintains these sort of things. Thus not having to pass along references and 'talk' to the parent directly instead.

Comment: Hi there! I've tried to initialize `VerticalViewPager` in the same Fragment that initializes the rest of the objects, but it still returns null after rotation. I'm amazed, because it _should_ reinitialize `VerticalViewPager` on rotation at this point.  

I tried using the singleton pattern (just for testing!) and even when referencing it as a static variable in a totally separate class, it returns null after rotation.

Comment: My suspision is that you might be calling for it too early in the restoring process (have no experience with VerticalViewPager). But if you ask for it before `FragSanningEllerKonsekvens` have had a chance to recreate the UI, I figure it might return null. Can you show the code for `getViewPager()` and `getVerticalViewPager()` respectively?

Comment: I've added the code you asked for in my original post @cYrixmorten. That might actually be the case. I'm a bit confused though; wouldn't it be somewhat impossible for the UI to recreate "too fast" since I'm sending the `VerticalViewPager` as an argument in every initialization?

Comment: I am not sure if those are the snippets I was thinking about. In `new PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens().newInstance(getViewPager(), getVerticalViewPager());` you call the methods `getViewPager()` and  `getVerticalViewPager()`. I assume it is here that you pass the references? Just wanted to know 1) how you obtain those references and 2) at exactly what point in 'lifecycle' time you ask for those references.

Comment: To test the idea about wanting the reference too early you can try and move some of your calls to `onviewstaterestored`

Comment: So I've updated my post once again. This time it makes it clear when things are initiated, I think. Which calls do you propose I move, @cYrixmorten? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this might not be a complete answer but I think it would be too long a comment.

I think you are right that the null pointer happens at getItem in the adapter. (a logcat report to confirm this would be nice). 
The reason for this (I think) is that the adapter tries to recreate the inner fragments before the inflation of the ViewPager is complete. Normally I create similar adapters in onCreate because it normally do not rely on anything but a fragmentmanager.

**Having this in mind, and the fact that you might have a hard time avoiding the null pointer in the current design, I propose a new design.**

Am only at my phone right now so is hard to give you the code I have in mind. For now I just sketch the idea:

- Move the getter/setter of ViewPagers from the adapter to FragSanningEllerKonsekvens, leaving the creation of TruthOrDarePagerAdapter only depend on fragment manager
- Now do the same for PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens making it simply PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens.newInstance() in getItem of the adapter
- Finally, you are now missing the reference to the ViewPagers in PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens PageFragSanningellerKonsekvens,  but remember you now have the getters of both ViewPagers in the parent FragSanningEllerKonsekvens

So the buttons now become:

```
((FragSanningEllerKonsekvens)getParentFragment()).getVerticalViewPager().setCurrentItem(0, true);
```

And

```
((FragSanningEllerKonsekvens)getParentFragment()).getVerticalViewPager().setCurrentItem(2, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! As you hinted about earlier a redesign seemed to be the best solution, so I did. Now the button that control the ViewPager is inflated in the same fragment. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure did! What should I do now? Should I mark the answer above as correct (since it proposes a redesign)? @cYrixmorten

Comment: Make the redesign-propsal bold and I'll tag it as the correct answer :-) Merry christmas @cYrixmorten!